# Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

Why does this code gives me the above compile time error?

```
var results = [[String:Bool]]()

var isSuccessful:Bool =
{
    for (index, element) in results.enumerated()
    {
        if element.values.contains(false) { return false }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: either `var isSuccessful:Bool = { ... }()` or `var isSuccessful:Bool { ... }`, it depends on whether you are happy to get this evaluating __once__ or you need to do it __every single time__ when you need to access its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `=` sign

```
var isSuccessful:Bool {
     get {
            for (index, element) in results.enumerated()
            {
                if element.values.contains(false) { return false }
            }
            return true
         }
    }
```

If you use the `=` sign, you want to 'assign' a value to your variable.
This is a common mistake to lazy var initialization

```
lazy var isSuccessful:Bool =  {
            for (index, element) in results.enumerated()
            {
                if element.values.contains(false) { return false }
            }
            return true
    }()
```

This syntax will process the block when you are getting the variable the first time.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @BadmintonCat any upvote / accept answer appreciated :)

Comment: The answer could do with an explanation as to why the `=` is wrong here.

Comment: @JeremyP Just proved it ;)

Comment: I was thinking more about explaining that the code in the question defines a boolean property but then tries to initialise it to a `() -> Void` closure.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases.

**1) Computed property:**

```
var isSuccessful:Bool
{
    for (index, element) in results.enumerated()
    {
        if element.values.contains(false) { return false }
    }
    return true
}
```

**2) Lazy variable:**

```
lazy var isSuccessful : Bool = 
{
    for (index, element) in results.enumerated()
    {
        if element.values.contains(false) { return false }
    }
    return true
}()
```

Both are correct. Choose the one you need.

Semantically:

- computed property is evaluated on every access.
- lazy variable is evaluated just once, on first access, but not on startup.